# local variable 'intent' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django

Can anyone please help me to fix this problem   local variable 'intent' referenced before assignment i could not find out why client_secret in the context is triggered. to my knowledge if the code in if statement fails then else block will be executed but i have set a print statement and it does not appear in the teminal either. if someone can please help me in solving this issue.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, reverse
from django.contrib import messages
from django.conf import settings

from .forms import OrderForm
from .models import Order, OrderLineItem, ProductLineItem, ExerciseLineItem, NutritionLineItem


from merchandise.models import Product
from exercise.models import ExercisePlans
from nutrition.models import NutritionPlans
from cart.contexts import cart_contents

import stripe


def checkout(request):
    stripe_public_key = settings.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY
    stripe_secret_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY

    if request.method == 'POST':
        cart = request.session.get('cart', {
            'merchandise_dic': {},
            'excercise_plans_dic': {},
            'nutrition_plans_dic': {},
        })
        form_data = {
            'full_name': request.POST['full_name'],
            'email': request.POST['email'],
            'phone_number': request.POST['phone_number'],
            'country': request.POST['country'],
            'postcode': request.POST['postcode'],
            'town_or_city': request.POST['town_or_city'],
            'street_address1': request.POST['street_address1'],
            'street_address2': request.POST['street_address2'],
            'county': request.POST['county'],
        }
        order_form = OrderForm(form_data)
        if order_form.is_valid():
            print("Order form is valid")
            order = order_form.save()
            for product_type, dic in cart.items():
                if product_type == 'merchandise_dic':
                    for item_id, quantity in dic.items():
                        print(f"This is item id of merchandise: {item_id}")
                        print(f"This is quantity of merchandise: {quantity}")
                        
                        product = Product.objects.get(id=item_id)
                        print(product)
                        order_line_item = ProductLineItem(
                            order=order,
                            product=product,
                            quantity=quantity,
                        )
                        order_line_item.save()
   
                elif product_type == 'excercise_plans_dic':
                    for item_id, quantity in dic.items():
                        print(f"This is item id of exercise plan: {item_id}")
                        print(f"This is quantity of exercise plan: {quantity}")
                        
                        product = ExercisePlans.objects.get(id=item_id)
                        print(product)
                        order_line_item = ExerciseLineItem(
                            order=order,
                            product=product,
                            quantity=quantity,
                        )
                        order_line_item.save()
                
                elif product_type == 'nutrition_plans_dic':
                    for item_id, quantity in dic.items():
                        print(f"This is item id of nutrition plan: {item_id}")
                        print(f"This is quantity of nutrition plan: {quantity}")
                        
                        product = NutritionPlans.objects.get(id=item_id)
                        print(product)
                        order_line_item = NutritionLineItem(
                            order=order,
                            product=product,
                            quantity=quantity,
                        )
                        order_line_item.save()
        else:
            print("Order form is invalid")        
            messages.error(request, ('There was an error with your form. '
                                    'Please double check your information.'))
            return redirect(reverse('checkout'))

    else:
        print("Order form is invalid")
        cart = request.session.get('cart', {
            'merchandise_dic': {},
            'excercise_plans_dic': {},
            'nutrition_plans_dic': {},
        })
        if not cart:
            messages.error(request,
                           "There is nothing in your \
                                shopping cart at the moment")
            return redirect(reverse('products'))

        """ Got total from cart_contents """
        current_cart = cart_contents(request)
        current_total = current_cart['total']
        stripe_total = round(current_total * 100)
        """ Set secret key on stripe """
        stripe.api_key = stripe_secret_key
        """ Created payment intent """
        intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
            amount=stripe_total,
            currency=settings.STRIPE_CURRENCY,
            )
        print(intent)
        order_form = OrderForm()

    if not stripe_public_key:
        messages.warning(request, 'Stripe public key is missing. \
            Did you forget to set it in your environment?')

    template = 'checkout/checkout.html'

    context = {
        'order_form': order_form,
        'stripe_public_key': stripe_public_key,
        'client_secret': intent.client_secret,
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: What do you get when you print out intent?

Comment: You need to initialise `intent` to something before diving into the `if` statement which only sets it in one branch!

Answer (score 0):

If your method == "POST": is true then the intent variable is not assigned any parameter.
context = {
'order_form': order_form,
'stripe_public_key': stripe_public_key,
'client_secret': intent.client_secret,
}
Hence, the intent in last section is not assigned anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
else:
        print("Order form is invalid")
        cart = request.session.get('cart', {
            'merchandise_dic': {},
            'excercise_plans_dic': {},
            'nutrition_plans_dic': {},
        })
        if not cart:
            messages.error(request,
                           "There is nothing in your \
                                shopping cart at the moment")
            return redirect(reverse('products'))

        """ Got total from cart_contents """
        current_cart = cart_contents(request)
        current_total = current_cart['total']
        stripe_total = round(current_total * 100)
        """ Set secret key on stripe """
        stripe.api_key = stripe_secret_key
        """ Created payment intent """
--->    intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
            amount=stripe_total,
            currency=settings.STRIPE_CURRENCY,
            )
        print(intent)
        order_form = OrderForm()
```

`intent` is assigned inside the `else` block, but it is referenced outside the `else` block

```
 context = {
        'order_form': order_form,
        'stripe_public_key': stripe_public_key,
 --->   'client_secret': intent.client_secret,
```

So if the `else` block is not executed there is no `intent` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks every one for your valuable input I found the problem and fixed it. Actually I was not returning anything if the form is valid! Thus I was missing the redirect to checkout_success page at the first for loop level before 1st else.
That is why even if the form is valid it's still trying to return the render() statement at the bottom which was causing this error. Thus I created a checkout_success view and and also checkout_success.html and redirected to it. like this and fixed this error.
return redirect(reverse('checkout_success',
args=[order.order_number]))